scroll up/down not working with Voice Control enabled users in Webview iOS
Accessibility settings > Voice control> Voice Control toggle button on/off.
Unable to scroll webview content by scroll up/down command.
Actual Result:
Voice control users are unable to scroll up/down the webview page page.
 
Expected Result:
By using scroll up/down commands, voice control users should be able to scroll the page.

You may try adding NSMicrophoneUsageDescription, NSCameraUsageDescription  and NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription in the info.plist.

I added above permissions. Still scroll up/ scroll down voice control commands not working in webview.

Could you share some relevant code about the XAML or how you design the webview? Right now, I cannot reproduce this issue on my side. I mean when I use voice control in my app (e.g. I say 'scroll down/up'), then the WebView can successfully scroll down/up.

I found the issue, the voice control commands not working in UIWebview, but working fine in WKWebview.

You could see this, Renderer Base Classes and Native Controls.  Xamarin Forms WebView is implemented by WKWebView for iOS. UIWebView is obsoleted in Xamarin Forms.

I am working on Xamarin ios native app. Thanks a lot for your support

Thanks for your sharing! @Niladri
To those who have similar questions, this issue may due to the use of the UIWebView, which is deprecated now.
Apple says that in apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView. And WKWebView works well with Voice Control.
By the way, Xamarin will be end of support from May. It is recommend that you migrate Xamarin App to MAUI. Here are some docs you may refer to,
Xamarin Support Policy
Upgrade from Xamarin to .NET
Hope it helps!
